# Excel: If cell contains string then add numbers

Tags: string, excel, formula

This is basically for a tournament in an RPG game to balance the teams out,

I am new to excel and was wondering how you could add numbers together if a cell contains a word.

First of all:

Bronze = 2 points

Silver = 4 points

Gold = 10 points

Platinum = 11 points

Diamond = 12 points

Maximum points you can have in a team = 25 points ( A team consists of 5 players )

So for example, in a team there can be 1x diamond player ( 12 points ), 2x silver players ( 8 points) and 2x bronze players ( 4 points ) and since you're allowed to have a maximum of 25 points, this team adds up to 24 points.

What would be the easiest way to create such a table?

Right now I have the following formula:

For cell H4, I have: =IF(G4="bronze",2,IF(G4="silver",4,IF(G4="gold",10,IF(G4="platinum",11,IF(G4="diamond",12,)))))

Then in cell G4, I write whether the player is bronze/silver/gold, etc.

Next in cell H5, I have: =IF(G5="bronze",2,IF(G5="silver",4,IF(G5="gold",10,IF(G5="platinum",11,IF(G5="diamond",12,)))))

And again, in G5 I have the players level (bronze/silver, etc.)

Is there a quicker way of creating this? I'm sure there is something much simpler which can be done with 1 formula on one cell?

Thank you very much

Comment: I just answered your question, but am wondering if I answered what you were asking... Can you elaborate on what it is you're looking to accomplish??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Vlookup` to accomplish this.

Choose an empty area of your sheet and put in the table you have above... For illustration's sake, imagine you put it in columns A & B, starting at A1.

So you would have the following:

```
A:        B:
Bronze    2
Silver    4
Gold      10
Platinum  11
Diamond   12
```

Now, in H4, put in the following Formula
    `= VLookup(G4, $A$1:$B$5, 2, 0)`

(Obviously, change the `$A$1:$B$5` reference to wherever you put your table)
And you can drag that down column H as is needed

Thank should do it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I see, so in the G4 cell, I would enter bronze, silver, etc. The $A$1:$B$5 is just the range it will search at, but what does the "2, 0" mean ? Thank you very much by the way :)

Comment: If you look up the `Vlookup` function (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx), you'll see that the second argument tells the function what column to look at for oyur return value - So, in this case, it will look at the first column (the rating name) and return the value from the second column (the rating value) because you put in a `2`. The third argument just tells it to find an Exact match.. The function description explains that better than I could here....

Comment: Ah.. it makes sense now, thanks a lot :) Just one last thing, when there is no value entered, I get #N/A, how can I change this to be blank ? Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working!! - Welcome to S.O.!

Comment: Any idea about the #N/A ? :/ I'd rather have the field blank when it's empty..

Comment: Just change the formula to this `=IfError(VLookup(G4, $A$1:$B$5, 2, 0),"")` - That should do it

Answer (score 0):

You could use VLOOKUP to read the value from a separate table.
Say you have this table of values.

```
   A        B
1  BRONZE    2
2  SILVER    4
3  GOLD     10 
4  PLATINUM 11
5  DIAMOND  12
```

`VLOOKUP("GOLD",A1:B5,2)` will return 10.
First parameter is what you are searching for, next parameter is the range you are searching in and then last one is the index of the column to be returned.

Comment: How come it returns 10 as soon as I enter the formula? How would the value change to 11 if a field would contain the word platinum ?